# How to query for objects that are in a given list of objects?

Tags: java, android, ormlite

I want to query for the objects that are similar to the objects from a list

Lets say I have a list L that contains objects A,C,F and the database contains objects A,B,C,D,E,...,Z

How do I query for objects in ormlite only the objects inside the list L?

**Edit:** the objects are custom class containing various fields and an integer id field as its primary key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I query for objects in ormlite only the objects inside the list L?

If I'm understanding the question, the best way to look up a collection of objects is to create a collection of the IDs of those objects and then use the `WHERE IN` clause.

```
 List<Integer> idList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
 for (MyClass instance : L) {
    idList.add(L.getId());
 }
 List<MyClass> results = dao.queryBuilder().where().in("id", idList).query();
```

You could choose any field from your `MyClass` to lookup using this metric but the id field will have an index so it's an easy choice.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm using the same thing.. is there a more optimal solution than this, something implemented in ormlite itself?

Comment: Sorry but no @GamatheGreat.

Answer (score 1):

Use `where in` clause

```
queryBuilder().where().in("field", L).query();
```

where `L` should be of type `List<String>`.

Comment: I am not sure. I always used it with lists.